# MX Linux に XAMPP をインストールしたい

Tags: linux, xampp

Virtualboxを入れMX Linux 21をインストールし仮想環境を構築しました。ホストOSはWindows11です。PHPを扱いたくXamppを入れようと試みています。

XamppのダウンロードページよりLinux向けのXamppをダウンロードしました。
ダウンロードフォルダには

「**xampp-linux-x64-8.0.12-0-installer.run**」

というファイルが入っています。

[image: mx linux]

Linuxのコマンドはほぼ分からないの「Linux Xampp インストール」のようなキーワード検索し比較的最近のサイトを見ながらそのままやってみました。

(参考)
https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/xampp/xamppinstalllinux.html
https://dailylife.pman-bros.com/lampp_install/

上記のサイト等を参考にヴァージョンを変えて

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-8.0.12-0-installer.run
```

などと打ってみたのですがうまく行きませんでした。

そこでダウンロードしたファイルを直接クリックしてみると「推奨のアプリケーションが入っていない」と出ます。
WindowsOSでXamppは利用しています。インストールも手順通り進めば問題なく使えています。
Linux、仮想環境に関しては右も左もわからないレベルです。手順も動画がサイトなどを観ながらやっています。

上記のような状況でどのようにすればXamppをインストールできますか？
わかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP 公式サイトの [FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html) にインストール方法が記載されています。

ダウンロードしたインストーラに `chmod` コマンドで実行権限を付けた後、`sudo` に続けてインストーラを指定することで管理者権限で実行します。

> #### How do I install XAMPP?
>
> Change the permissions to the installer
>
> ```sh
> chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run
> ```
>
> Run the installer
>
> ```sh
> sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
> ```